# Choice of ridge parameter in constrained estimation

Tags: regression, ridge-regression, regularization, constrained-regression

Apologies for a possible basic question. Suppose I have a model 
$$y=X\beta + \epsilon, \quad E[\epsilon|X]=0, \quad X \text{ is } n \times k$$ 
and, say, matrix $X'X$ is nearly singular and I have a pretty good idea of how to choose a ridge tuning parameter $\lambda_1$ to consider the ridge estimator 
$$\hat{\beta}_{ridge}=(X'X+\lambda_1 I)^{-1} X'y.$$

Now I think that the true parameter $\beta$ satisfies certain linear constraints -- e.g. $\beta_1 \leq \beta_2 \leq \ldots \leq \beta_k$, so I want to implement ridge-type idea in the constrained estimation. Essentially, I am thinking of just conducting *constrained* quadratic programming in Matlab with $X'X+\lambda_2 I$ corresponding to the quadratic term in $\beta$ and  $-2X'y$ corresponding to the linear term in $\beta$.

My questions:

(a) Does my idea make sense statistically?

(b) Should I expect $\lambda_2$ that works well (close to something optimal) in *constrained* estimation be smaller or larger than $\lambda_1$ I had in the unconstrained estimation? Basically, I want to know the direction in which to search for $\lambda_2$.